# Is it possible to use python time series business days to generate month end time series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on analyzing assets monthly return based on factors using alphalens. My problem is that my dataframe is a multi-index dataframe with date and asset as index.

```
                    factor_score
date         asset
2000-01-30    0001     0.2
2000-01-30    0002     0.1
2000-01-30    0003     -0.2
2000-02-29    0001.    0.1
2000-02-29    0004.    0.4
2000-03-31
```

As I am analyzing month-end prices, the frequency of date is 'M'(I used MonthEnd as an offset to get month-end dates). For alphalens, the freq requirement for time series is: freq must be Day, BDay or CustomBusinessDay. I would like to convert the freq of date to meet the requirements.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Using BDay(21), this does not work as adding 21 business days does not always return month-end time series (for example, I got 2000-01-31, 2000-02-29, 2000-03-29, 2000-04-27). It is neither month-end date, nor business month-end date.
2. I saw some suggestion of

```
df.resample('M').last()
```

but this will only keep the last row of each month-end, not all the data entries.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a time-series index on a month-end basis and then extracting the data frames from it.
Set the frequency of the end of the business day with 'BM' of `pd.date_range(...,freq='BM')`.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

with open('./alpha_vantage_api_key.txt') as f:
    api_key = f.read()

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31)

df_aapl = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'av-daily', start, end, api_key=api_key)
df_aapl.index = pd.to_datetime(df_aapl.index)
date_rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='BM')

df_aapl[df_aapl.index.isin(date_rng)]
    open    high    low close   volume
2018-01-31  166.8700    168.4417    166.50  167.43  30984099
2018-02-28  179.2600    180.6150    178.05  178.12  33604574
2018-04-30  162.1302    167.2600    161.84  165.26  42427424
2018-05-31  187.2200    188.2300    186.14  186.87  27482793
2018-06-29  186.2900    187.1900    182.91  185.11  22737666
2018-07-31  190.3000    192.1400    189.34  190.29  39373038
2018-08-31  226.5100    228.8700    226.00  227.63  43340134
2018-09-28  224.7900    225.8400    224.02  225.74  22929364
2018-10-31  216.8800    220.4500    216.62  218.86  38358933
2018-11-30  180.2900    180.3300    177.03  178.58  39531549
2018-12-31  158.5300    159.3600    156.48  157.74  35003466
....
```